# How to fix java.lang.StackOverflowError in java

Tags: java, stack, stack-overflow

I'm writing an application that needs to use the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi, now I couldn't get pi4j to work so I just wrote the code in python and called it with java. Now I'm running this code to call my python script but I keep getting an overflow error and I'm not sure why this is my code

Gpio_On.java

```
package Controller;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Gpio_On extends Thread {
    public String Pin;

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        Pin = pin;
    }

    public void start() {
        Gpio_On thread = new Gpio_On();
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("in thread for gpio on PIN:" + Pin);
        try {
            System.out.println("python3 /home/pi/gpioOn.py " + Pin);
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 /home/pi/gpioOn.py " + Pin);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Terminal

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize(AccessControlContext.java:632)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.getContext(AccessController.java:839)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:440)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:704)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:473)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.<init>(Gpio_On.java:5)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:13)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
    at Controller.Gpio_On.start(Gpio_On.java:14)
this error keeps going for a long time
```

Comment: `thread.start()` calls itself at line 14. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually overriding start(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()
Just remove it and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

when making a thread start you would pass `thread.start` but there's also a function in that class called `start` so when calling `thread.start` it's running the function that's already running so it throws an error